# Change last line in QTextBrowser

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qtextbrowser, qtextcursor

I have a `QTextBrowser` that displays lines of `QString` and an `Int`. The messages looks something like this:

> Message a counter 1
>
> Message a counter 2
>
> Message a counter 3
>
> Message b counter 1

Instead of always appending a new line for each incrementation of the counter I want to just increment the `Int` in the last message (the last line). What is the most efficient way to do this?

I came up with this code to remove only the last line in the `QTextBrowser`:

```
ui->outputText->append(messageA + QString::number(counter));
ui->outputText->moveCursor( QTextCursor::End, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor );
ui->outputText->moveCursor( QTextCursor::StartOfLine, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor );
ui->outputText->moveCursor( QTextCursor::End, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor );
ui->outputText->textCursor().removeSelectedText();
ui->outputText->append(messageA + QString::number(++counter));
```

Unfortunately this leaves me with an empty line after removing the last line which looks very ugly. What is the best way to achieve this that doesn't involve clearing the whole `QTextBroswer`and appending each line again.

Comment: Would you be OK with deleting the last line and reappending? I can give you code for that if that is okay...

Comment: Yes thats what I am trying to do. The way I did it in my example I am left with an empty line after deleting the last line which doesn't look nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my solution, but mind you that it requires C++11 and Qt 5.4 at least to build and run. However, the concept is there that you can copy and paste out without using `QTimer` requiring those versions above:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTextBrowser>
#include <QTextCursor>
#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication application(argc, argv);
    int count = 1;
    QString string = QStringLiteral("Message a counter %1");
    QTextBrowser *textBrowser = new QTextBrowser();
    textBrowser->setText(string.arg(count));
    QTimer::singleShot(2000, [textBrowser, string, &count](){
        QTextCursor storeCursorPos = textBrowser->textCursor();
        textBrowser->moveCursor(QTextCursor::End, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
        textBrowser->moveCursor(QTextCursor::StartOfLine, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
        textBrowser->moveCursor(QTextCursor::End, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
        textBrowser->textCursor().removeSelectedText();
        textBrowser->textCursor().deletePreviousChar();
        textBrowser->setTextCursor(storeCursorPos);
        textBrowser->append(string.arg(++count));
    });
    textBrowser->show();
    return application.exec();
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT += widgets
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

Comment: Seems like the only thing I was missing was `textCursor().deletePreviousChar();` in order to get rid of the empty line.  Now it works as intended. Thank you.

Comment: @testus: yup, no worries :)